# Gradle build failed with : Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

Gradle Build fails with following exception (adding --stacktrace)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
> Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:79)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:45)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.createRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:85)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceLookupException: Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.findProviderMethods(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$1.addProvider(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:229)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CompileServices.registerGradleServices(CompileServices.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices$1.execute(GradleScopeServices.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices$1.execute(GradleScopeServices.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.register(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:206)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices.<init>(GradleScopeServices.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServiceRegistryFactory.createFor(BuildScopeServiceRegistryFactory.java:38)
        at org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.<init>(DefaultGradle.java:88)
        at org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.AsmBackedClassGenerator.newInstance(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:179)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.AbstractClassGenerator$GeneratedClassImpl$GeneratedConstructorImpl.newInstance(AbstractClassGenerator.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:49)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultJdkToolsInitializer.initializeJdkTools(DefaultJdkToolsInitializer.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CompileServices$GradleScopeCompileServices.configure(CompileServices.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.applyConfigureMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:193)
        ... 68 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**Gradle Version**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-10-18 00:28:36 UTC
Revision:     bd168bbf5d152c479186a897f2cea494b7875d13

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.9 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.9+7-LTS)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-42-generic amd64
```

**Java Version**

```
java -version
java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Build was executing perfectly fine, but after deleting generated build folder, when I try to rebuild it fails with above exception.
I have upgraded gradle version from v3.4 to v5.6.3 and Java version from JDK8 to JDK11.
I have already tried deleting .gradle folder but no results.

Build passed if I run gradle build with JDK 8 and gradle v5.6.3

Comment: were you using an ide

Comment: No, I am using terminal to execute build command(gradle build)

Comment: Looks to me like the failed build is still using Gradle 3.x which does not support Java 11. Maybe you mixed up  `gradle` and `gradlew` ? If not, how did you upgrade Gradle - with the wrapper?

Comment: I have added gradle-5.6.3-all.zip under gradle/wrapper/ folder and in gradle-wrapper-properties file specified distributionUrl=gradle-5.6.3-all.zip. Also, I downloaded gradle and placed the unzip folder under /public/gradle and have set environment variable.
I am working on Virtual Box not having access to internet.

Comment: Maybe it could not download gradle.

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.3-bin.zip

Comment: I am working on Virtual box that doesnot have internet connection. So will it be able to download from this URL. Hence, I placed the downloaded zip under /gradle/wrapper/ folder

Comment: gradle build -Dorg.gradle.java.home="/public/java/jdk1.8.0_40" solves the issue but does that mean I am compiling using JDK8 and not JDK11

Comment: please try this solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510359/could-not-create-an-instance-of-type-org-gradle-invocation-defaultgradle/68519478#68519478) it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

set ./android/build.gradle file to newer version:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```