# Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm unable to build and run my flutter project. Every time I run the project it gives me this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
>   Could not configure services using GradleScopeCompileServices.configure().

I searched and tried the following solution but nothing has worked so far:

1. Clean & Build Project
2. Deleted .gradle & .dart_tools folder
3. Downgraded Gradle version

I'm using Android studio 4.2.1. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When and where do you see this error? when running `flutter run` or inside your IDE? If the second one, did you try to just launch your app with `flutter run`?

Comment: in either case, it giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions but the following worked for me:

1. Downgraded flutter version from **2.2.3** to **2.2.2**
2. Deleted ~/.android folder and then run the flutter project. Everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am use Flutter 2.5, same issue.

set ./android/build.gradle file to newer version:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}